# Evaluate $\int \frac{\cos^2x}{1+\tan x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $\int \dfrac{\cos^2x}{1+\tan x}dx$

Here are my various unsuccessful attempts:-

**Attempt $1$:**

$$\tan x=t$$
$$\sec^2 x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}$$
$$\ln(1+t)=y$$
$$\dfrac{1}{1+t}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\int \dfrac{dy}{\left(1+(e^y-1)^2\right)^2}$$
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{(1+e^{2y}+1-2e^y)^2}$$
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{(e^{2y}+2-2e^y)^2}$$
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{e^4y+4+4e^{2y}+4e^{2y}-4e^y(e^{2y}+2)}$$
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{e^4y-4e^{3y}+8e^{2y}-8e^y+4}$$

From here I gave up on this method.

**Attempt $2$:**

$$\int \dfrac{\cos^3x}{\cos x+\sin x}$$
$$\int\dfrac{3\cos x+\cos 3x}{4(\cos x+\sin x)}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{4}\left(3\cdot\int\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos x+\sin x}+\int \dfrac{\cos 3x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right)$$

Solving the first integral

$$\cos x=A(\cos x+\sin x)+B(-\sin x+\cos x)+C$$
$$A+B=1$$
$$A-B=0$$
$$A=\dfrac{1}{2},B=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\left(x+\ln|\sin x+\cos x|\right)+\int \dfrac{\cos 3x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right)$$

I was not understanding how to proceed for second integration.

**Attempt $3$:**

For @mvpq

$$\tan x=t$$
$$\sec^2 x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}$$

Trying to write expression as 
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=\dfrac{A}{1+t}+\dfrac{B}{1+t^2}+\dfrac{C}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=\dfrac{A(1+t^2)^2+B(1+t^2)+C(1+t)}{(1+t)(1+t^2)^2}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=(A+B+C)+Ct+(B+2A)t^2+At^4$$
$$A+B+C=1\tag{1}$$

$$A=0$$
$$A+2B=0$$
$$B=0$$
$$C=0$$

But $A+B+C=1$, hence no solution, so cannot be solved by partial fractions.

**Attempt $4$:**

For @heropup

$$\tan x=t$$
$$\sec^2 x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}$$

Trying to write expression as 
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=\dfrac{A}{1+t}+\dfrac{Bt+C}{1+t^2}+\dfrac{Dt+E}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=\dfrac{A(1+t^2)^2+(Bt+C)(1+t^2)(1+t)+(Dt+E)(1+t)}{(1+t)(1+t^2)^2}$$

$$1=A(1+t^2)^2+(Bt+C)(1+t^2)(1+t)+(Dt+E)(1+t)$$

Placing $t=-1$ in the equation

$$4A=1, A=\dfrac{1}{4}$$
$$1=(Bt+C)(1+t+t^2+t^3)+(Dt+Dt^2+E+Et)$$
$$1=Bt+Bt^2+Bt^3+Bt^4+C+Ct+Ct^2+Ct^3+Dt+Dt^2+E+Et$$

$$1=Bt^4+(B+C)t^3+(B+C+D)t^2+(B+C+D+E)t+(C+E)$$
$$B=0$$
$$B+C=0$$
$$C=0$$
$$B+C+D=0$$
$$D=0$$
$$B+C+D+E=0$$
$$E=0$$
$$C+E=1$$
$$E=1$$

This is contradiction right?

Any hints?

Comment: In your attempt 1, instead of substituting $\log(1+t)=y$, I would try writing the integrand in partial fractions

Comment: @mvpq, added attempt 3 for you, got no solution by partial fractions.

Comment: Your partial fraction decomposition is wrong - see heropup's answer

Comment: @mvpq, added the attempt 4 for you with correct decomposition, got no solutions

Comment: In attempt 4, you missed a factor: $(Bt+C)(1+t)(1+t^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Your partial fraction decomposition fails because the appropriate choice for numerators are not constants, but instead $$\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)} = \frac{A}{1+t} + \frac{Bt + C}{1+t^2} + \frac{Dt + E}{(1+t^2)^2}.$$  When the denominator is an integer power of a quadratic polynomial, the numerator is a linear function of $t$.

---

In order to solve for the coefficients in a correct manner, you need to first collect all of the terms on the RHS over a common denominator; this you have done:

$$\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)} = \frac{A(1+t^2)^2 + (Bt+C)(1+t)(1+t^2) + (Dt+E)(1+t)}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}.$$

Next, you need to equate the numerator on the LHS with the numerator on the RHS:

$$1 = A(1+t^2)^2 + (Bt+C)(1+t)(1+t^2) + (Dt+E)(1+t).$$

Here is where you make a mistake:  You need to expand the RHS as a polynomial in $t$ and then collect like terms in $t$:

$$1 = (A+B) t^4 + (B+C) t^3 + (2A + B + C + D) t^2 + (B + C + D + E)t + (A + C + E).$$

After this, you equate corresponding coefficients to obtain the system
$$\begin{cases} 1 &= A + C + E \\
0 &= B + C + D + E \\
0 &= 2A + B + C + D \\
0 &= B + C \\
0 &= A + B \end{cases}$$

Moreover, your substitution trick was performed incorrectly.  When $t = -1$, you would get $$1 = A(1 + (-1)^2)^2 = 4A,$$ hence $A = 1/4$.  I do not understand how you got $A = 0$.

Comment: added the attempt 4 for you, got no solution.

Comment: @user3290550 While computationally tedious, it is important to check your work thoroughly before concluding no solution exists.

Comment: you are right. I also wanted to know the reason, what is the reason for placing linear term in numerator when there is quadratic in denominator.

Also can we conclude that we should always make numerator $1$ degree less than denominator?

Comment: @user3290550 Please review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition for a detailed explanation of this technique.

Comment: I ended with same integral after applying partial fraction, see my 4th attempt.

Comment: @user3290550 You are substituting a value for $t$ before expanding and collecting coefficients in $t$.  This is wrong.  You cannot do that, for reasons that I will make clear shortly in an edit to my answer.

Comment: ok but you can clearly see right, A,B,C,D all will come zero and $E$ will come $1$ right?, just try expanding

Comment: @user3290550 It is disappointing that, even after having asked you to check your work and be absolutely sure your computations are correct, you seem to be under the impression that the other responders (including myself) are somehow to be doubted.  This pattern strongly suggests to me that you need to work on your basic computational proficiency rather than any specific techniques of integration.

Comment: @user3290550 Once you obtained a nonzero value for $A$, why do you proceed with the remainder of the computation as if $A = 0$?  You cannot do that.  Your equation cannot begin with $1 = Bt^4 + \cdots$.  As I showed you in my answer, the coefficient of $t^4$ is $A + B$, not $B$.

Comment: sorry for that, I was not getting the correct result, hence was feeling frustrated.

Comment: @user3290550 My advice to you is to follow the steps I have outlined in my answer, one by one.  Check for yourself each step and ask yourself if you agree.  If so, proceed to solve the system in five equations in five unknowns.  If not, tell me where you disagree.  Don't try some hybrid approach with substitutions and some other stuff.  Mathematics is not a race about who is fastest.  It is about making sure you have a solid logical foundation at each step.

Answer (score 1):

To find $A,B,C,D,E$, you should have:
$$A(1+t^2)^2+(Bt+C)(1+t)(1+t^2)+(Dt+E)(1+t)=1$$
Then equate coefficients.

Writing the integrand in partial fractions, we have
$$\int \dfrac{dt}{(1+t^2)^2(1+t)}=\int\left(\frac{1}{4(1+t)}+\frac{1-t}{4(1+t^2)}+\frac{1-t}{2(1+t^2)^2}\right)\,dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\log(1+t)+\frac{1}{4}\arctan t-\frac{1}{8}\log(1+t^2)+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1-t}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt$$
To evaluate the last integral, split it up:
$$\int\frac{-t}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt=\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}$$
and for the integral below, substitute $t=\tan u$:
$$\int\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt=\int\frac{\sec^2 u}{\sec^4u}\,du=\int \cos^2u\,du=\ldots$$

Comment: unfortunately your solution is wrong, see my 4th attempt, you will get.

Comment: @user3290550 Where is my answer wrong? There are still mistakes in your latest attempt: putting $t=-1$ gives $A=1/4$

Comment: @user3290550 If you put $t=-1$ you have $1=A(1+(-1)^2)^2$, or $1=4A$, so $A=1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

You may continue and finish the second approach as follows,

$$I=\dfrac{1}{4}\int\dfrac{3\cos x+\cos3x}{\cos x+\sin x}dx$$

Rewrite the term $\cos3x $ in the integrand as
$\cos3x = (\cos2x-\sin2x)(\sin x+ \cos x)+\sin x$ and the integral becomes

$$I=\dfrac{1}{4}\int\left(2+\cos2x-\sin2x+\dfrac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x+\sin x}\right)dx$$

$$=\frac x2+\frac18(\sin2x+\cos2x)+\frac14\ln|\sin x+\cos x|+C$$

Comment: $$\cos 3x=cos(x+2x)-sin(2x-x)+sinx$$, you did this right?, how did you get this idea?

Comment: @user3290550 - I knew how to factorize  $\cos3x - \sin x =0$ without raising powers.